# Trac: "Waiting On" plugin?

Tags: trac

Sometimes an issue can't be resolved until someone else does something, or until some event occurs. Is there an add-on for trac that adds a field for these situations?

Answer (score 2):

I use a `needinfo` keyword for such issues.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [AdvancedTicketWrokflowPlugin on trac-hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin).  You can use `set_owner_to_previous` and `set_status_to_previous` to implement a `needinfo` state in your ticket workflow.  In fact, a `needinfo` action is the example given on that page.

<sub>Disclosure: I wrote the AdvancedTicketWorkflowPlugin and am a Trac developer.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [MasterTickets](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MasterTicketsPlugin) plugin?  It adds a "blocked by" field, which is the equivalent of "waiting on".  This is for dependencies between bugs, where Bug 101 can't be solved until Bug 102 is.

Comment: Cool! But I don't think it want it to be dependent on other *tickets*. I'm thinking more about "waiting for email reply from XXX"